# pass javascript variable to the php code

Tags: php, javascript

I have one question.. I want to pass javascript variable to php script, on the same page as javascript is located...
I have second code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getID(i)
    {
        var table = document.getElementById("tblPersons");
        var row = table.rows[i];    
        alert(row.id);

        //window.location.href = window.location+"?id="+row.id;

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: {'variable': row.id},
        });
    }
</script>

$selected_row = $_POST['variable'];
echo $selected_row;
                            }
```

but if I try to `var_dump $_post['variable']`, I got null in echo...

so can anyone help with my problem?

Comment: You have `$_POST['value']` and `$_POST['variable']`, which one is correect?

Comment: emmm, no mater... I just deleted if statement and also got null in var_dump

Comment: Where exactly are you checking for the output? Are you expecting it to be there right in the same page underneath the script?

Comment: @deceze, yes have javascript and php code on the same page

Answer (score 0):

See [Reference: Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor)

The code is executed like this:

1. server executes any PHP (including your `var_dump`, which echoes nothing)
2. servers sends resulting HTML/Javascript code to browser
3. browser parses HTML and executes Javascript
4. Javascript sends AJAX request to server
5. server receives request and executes PHP code, this time outputting something
6. Javascript receives the response of the AJAX call (no visible output yet)
7. you do nothing with the received result

Watch the Network tab of your browser debugging tool of choice (Firebug for Firefox, Web Inspector for Chrome/Safari) to see what's really happening.